# Can i3 automatically adjust to changed resolutions?

Tags: i3

Can i3 be configured to automatically handle changing resolutions? Right now, if I change the resolution on my machine, i3 still draws everything as if it was the old resolution. (Usually resulting in drawing mostly off screen.) How can I get i3 to detect a changed resolution and do the right thing?

Comment: As long as the monitors don’t overlap i3 seems to pick changes up reliable on my installation. (When they overlap, it still picks changes up, but the result is strange. Moving monitors around with `xrandr` to avoid overlap solves that problem then.)

Answer (score 0):

How are you changing resolution? You can use xrandr to set resolution

```bash
xrandr --output [device-name] --mode [resolution]
```

Its GUI [arandr](https://christian.amsuess.com/tools/arandr/) can generate scripts to set outputs and resolution which makes multi-monitor setups easier. You can execute these scripts through your i3 config when you reload i3.

Comment: I am using xrandr. The issue is not setting the resolution. The issue is that i3 does not pick up on the change in resolution and so doesn't display properly.

Comment: What do you get with `xrandr -q` when you change the resolution? Does the correct resolution show up as available?

Comment: Yes. The resolution changes just fine. The issue is that i3 then tries to draw off screen.